# change background height with repeating-linear-gradient

Tags: css

I have this "striped background" on a input type="range". The stripes are vertical. I can't manage to control the background height (the stripes height). When I change the `background height` value, the height stays 100% of the input type="range". Can you help please ?

HTML:

```
<form oninput="amount.value=userlevelofsurfing.value">
                <div class="range">
                    <input id="levelrange" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" name="userlevelofsurfing">
                 <output id="levelrangeoutput" name="amount" for="userlevelofsurfing">5</output>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#levelrange {
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  to right,
  rgba(255,255,255,0),
  rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%,
  #06b4c8 10%,
  #06b4c8 30%,
  rgba(255,255,255,0) 30%,
  rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%
);
background-size: 9.7% 5px;
}
```

Comment: I am very confused as to what you are asking...

Comment: @SimplyCraig thanks Craig, I just edited to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the stripes height by specifying a height to that element:

```css
#levelrange {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10%, #06b4c8 10%, #06b4c8 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background-size: 9.7% 5px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<form oninput="amount.value=userlevelofsurfing.value">
    <div class="range">
        <input id="levelrange" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" name="userlevelofsurfing" />
        <output id="levelrangeoutput" name="amount" for="userlevelofsurfing">5</output>
    </div>
</form>
```